# How to use stream to filter a collection in a range

Tags: java, collections, lambda, java-8, java-stream

I have a domain as person

```
public class Person{
  String name;
}
```

I have a list String of person names, like

```
listRange = new ListWith("Bob","John","Mark");
```

And how can I use Java 8 stream to filter in resultList, which person has the name in this range list.
It might be like

```
resultList.stream().filter(p->p.getName().equals(listRange.any).collect();
```

How can I use Lambda to filter the resultList?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What you are looking for is just the [`contains`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#contains-java.lang.Object-) method:

```
resultList.stream().filter(p -> listRange.contains(p.getName()))
                   .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

If your name list is only used to filter out persons from your result, you should consider using a `Set` as its `contains` method is O(1) (constant-time) so it will result in better performance.